# What is an equivalent condition for a quadratic form to be bounded from below?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ where $a, c >0$ are fixed and $x,y$ are real variables.

Then, what is the condition on $b$ that is equivalent to that $f(x,y)$ is bounded from below?

I know it is an elementary calculus..but I cannot remember the way through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By scaling, and relabeling, we may assume that the quadratic form is $$f(x, y) = x^2 + 2bxy + cy^2$$
for $c > 0$ and $b \in \Bbb R$. Completing the square gives $$f(x, y) = (x + by)^2 + (c - b)y^2.$$
If $c - b \ge 0$, then the above is bounded below by $0$.

On the other hand, if $c - b < 0$, then taking $y$ arbitrarily large and $x = -by$ shows that $f(x, y)$ takes arbitrarily small values (i.e., negative and with arbitrarily large magnitude) and thus, is not bounded below.

Thus, for our special case, we get $c \ge b$ as a necessary and sufficient condition. I leave it to you to translate it back to your set-up.

---

**Edit:** I didn't even use that $c > 0$.